# Screen freeze for 20 seconds after automatic login

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, login, multiple-monitors, mouse

I'm sorry if this question has already been solved but I've failed to find the answer. For some reason after ubuntu bootup and automatically login keyboard/mouse are frozen for 20-30 seconds. Screens are duplicated too. Then after 15-20 seconds it applies my default configuration (Extended with launcher on my 23" screen only") and mouse/keyboard are back. I've checked /var/log/syslog but nothing catched my eye. Could be because I'm not sure what to look for.

Any ideas how to fix this issue so that I don't have to wait for 20 seconds? It's not 20 seconds that bothers me - it's that something is not initializing correctly and it needs 20 seconds to recovers and start working.

Hope someone will have an idea :)

**UPDATE [lspci -k]**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost DirectCU II OC
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

**UPDATE [interesting part from /var/log/syslog]**

```
Aug 16 14:30:06 intruder-mainframe kernel: [   36.509330] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Aug 16 14:30:11 intruder-mainframe kernel: [   41.618694] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Aug 16 14:30:11 intruder-mainframe kernel: [   41.722450] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

**UPDATE [after installing nvidia drivers]**
Ok so I had to switch apt-get repository to "Main Server" and it showed me additional proprietary drivers. I've installed one mentioned below (yes it was offered in a list) and now when Ubuntu boots I first see terminal line

```
 [    0.450594] ACPI PCC probe failed.
```

After which same thing happens. I've searched my /var/log/syslog and several lines below ACPI PCC probe failed I see this:

```
[    0.450594] ACPI PCC probe failed.
....
Aug 16 14:57:04 *****-****** nvidia-persistenced: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 116 has read and write permissions for those files.
Aug 16 14:57:04 *****-****** nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Aug 16 14:57:04 *****-****** nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (663)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Done. I'll add some interesting stuff from syslog too but it may not be related to this issue. (To another issue that I hope will fix soon - still googling).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install video driver. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and reboot.

If that does not work well, install another driver

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: Will do right now. Any ideas why it's not offering drivers through update anymore? I've been on Windows for the last year but I remember that on 12.04 first thing after clean install was "Please install third-party drivers". When I did not saw that I thought it's already installed.

Comment: It is not offered, but you can find them in System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Comment: After switching repositories and `apt-get update` it was offered and I installed it (no problems at that time). After reboot same thing happened and I've updated post with /var/log/syslog messages that I suspect are related to this issue.

**edit**: lspci -k is not showing that Kernel driver in use is nvidia.

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get install nvidia-346`.

Comment: Nop - same issue stil...

Comment: Updated the answer